# How to extract integer from string in Linux kernel space?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to extract integers from string, e.g. I want to extract 0 as group identifier and 1 as mdev identifier from string "/dev/nkdev/group0/mdev1".

In the above string "/dev/nkdev/group" is a fixed pattern in input, group id may be any integer between 0-9 and "mdev" is also not fixed, it may be any character sequence followed by an integer.

I used following code

```
#define NO_INTEGER "%0[^0-9]"

res = sscanf(dev_name_p, NO_INTEGER "%u" NO_INTEGER "%u",
             &group_id, &mdev_id);
```

But I found skip sequence is not supported in kernel. Can any body tell, if there is any kernel library function to do the job?

Comment: Isn't it possible to use the format `/dev/nkdev/group%u/mdev%u`?

Comment: Thanks, It could have been possible if mdev was a fixed pattern, In my case mdev is also not a fixed. it may be any character sequence.

Comment: Then what about `/dev/nkdev/group%u/%*s%u`?

Comment: @bzeaman this should be the accepted answer, you should post as one!

Comment: @IshayPeled It didn't work, I later on discovered. The `%*s` also includes the digit following the `mdev` part. In his question he states 'skip sequences' are not supported, and I think he means formats like `%*[a-z]` with that. I posted it as an answer anyway, it may help others.

Comment: For the first glance you are doing something wrong when you need to parse such a string in kernel. Is there any other way to get those integers? If it's still the case, you have to use `simple_strtoul()` and your own loop to parse all numbers from that.

Answer (score 3):

**kstrtoint()** — convert a string to an int.

**kstrtol()** — convert a string to a long.

You check declaration  in linux kernel soruce tree **/include/linux/kernel.h**.you will have to include this header file **#include< linux/kernel.h>** before using this fuction.

```
 Example :

    const char *buf = "123";
    long value;
    if(kstrtoint(buf, 10, &value) != 0)
         return -1;
     printk("%d",value);
```

Comment: This will not work for strings that do not consist exclusively of digits, test your solution with "/dev/nkdev/group1/mdev2"

Comment: This indeed does not work, and does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

A format string like I use in this example should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        unsigned a = 38, b = 38; // Default magic value
        int n = sscanf("/dev/nkdev/group0/abc1", "/dev/nkdev/group%u/%*[a-z]%u", &a, &b);

        printf("n: %i, a: %u, b: %u\n", n, a, b);

        return 0;
}
```

It yields this output:

```
n: 2, a: 0, b: 1
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, quick, simple and works on all cases

Comment: It does't work in Linux kernel space as '%*[a-z]' sequence formatting is not supported in Kernel space. I used similar approach in my code which works fine with libc but doesn't work in kernel space.

Answer (score -2):

This solution runs in userspace, but all functions used here are available in kernel space with the same result

Dirty, but it will work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char string[] = "/dev/nkdev/group4/mdev12";
    char *stringp = (char *)&string;
    const char delimiters[] = "/";
    char *token;
    int num1, num2;

    token = strsep (&stringp, delimiters);        /* token => "" */
    token = strsep (&stringp, delimiters);        /* token => "dev" */
    token = strsep (&stringp, delimiters);        /* token => "nkdev" */
    token = strsep (&stringp, delimiters);        /* token => "group0" */
    while (*token != 0 && (*token < '0' || *token > '9'))
        token++;
    num1 = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
    token = strsep (&stringp, delimiters);        /* token => "mdev1" */
    while (*token != 0 && (*token < '0' || *token > '9'))
        token++;
    num2 = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
    printf("num1: %d\nnum2: %d\n", num1, num2);
}
```